# handle-callback-err Expected error to be handled

Tags: javascript, error-handling, vue.js, jslint, eslint

I have `eslint` enabled in my vue webapp, I have following code:

```
myApi.get('products/12').then((prodResponse) => {
  state.commit('ADD_PRODUCT', {product: prodResponse.data})
},
error => {
  console.log('Inside error, fetching product line items failed')
  router.push({path: '/'})
})
```

This is the error handling I want to do, still I get following error from the liner:

> ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/handle-callback-err  Expected error to be handled
>     ~/vue/src/store/modules/myStore.js:97:9
>             error => {

I can add following comment to convert this into warning:

```
/* eslint handle-callback-err: "warn" */
```

But how do I suppress this completely or modify code, so that this error doesn't come.

Comment: try writing error as (error) error has more than one arguement

Comment: change `warn` to `off` can suppress it completely...

Answer (score 41):

Just had the same thing, and the warning message is misleading; it's actually because `error` is not *referenced* in the code, not because it's not "handled".

Make sure you do something with error, such as a `console.log()` or don't include it as an argument:

```
// do something with error:
error => {
  console.log('Inside error, fetching product line items failed', error)
  router.push({path: '/'})
}

// don't define argument:
() => {
  console.log('Inside error, fetching product line items failed')
  router.push({path: '/'})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
error => {
  console.log('Inside error, fetching product line items failed', error)
  router.push({path: '/'})
}
```

if there is an error, you need to handle it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the things which have worked so far, from the help of comments:

if I put an `if` condition like following, error does not come:

```
error => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Inside error, fetching product line items failed')
    router.push({path: '/'})
  }
}
```

If I don't want to change the code, putting following will suppress the error completely:

```
/* eslint handle-callback-err: "warn" */
```

Looking forward to any better suggestions.

Comment: did you try this ?
Try writing error as (error) error has more than one arguement

Comment: @VinodLouis You mean like this : `(error) => router.push({path: '/'})`, which did not worked.

Comment: (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Inside error, fetching product line items failed')
    router.push({path: '/'})
  }
}

Comment: Yes, that works, however, for this get promise it will come in error block only in case of error, so that `if(error)` block looks redundant to me.

Comment: then try it like this (error) => {router.push({path: '/'})}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129092/discussion-between-saurabh-and-vinod-louis).